# links don't work in chrome

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm in the middle of a project and top navigation links don't work in chrome.

When you click on them nothing happens

This is the website http://www.blackcountrydesigns.co.uk/examples/green

Thanks in advance

Comment: works fine for me. chrome 25.0.1364.172

Comment: people really hate "this doesn't work, fix it" questions

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time.  Its still not working for me but it must be something wrong with my version of chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the code? They don't go anywhere...

```
<li><a class="entypo-home active" href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="entypo-briefcase" href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a class="entypo-picture" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a class="entypo-address" href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: The home one doesn't work as well.

Comment: @DavidAllen Works fine for me. I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.43

Comment: Maybe the page is cached? Hit `CTRL` + `F5`

Comment: I tried clearing cache.  I have finally got it working by not including js/init.js Strange fualt.  Thank you for you help anyway.